# A partial differential equation

Tags: partial-derivative, chain-rule

I have to differentiate with respect to $t_2$ on both sides of the following equation: $\dfrac{\partial c(x(t_2))}{\partial x} = p- t_2$. Can I do that in the following way?-

$\dfrac{\partial^2 c}{\partial x^2}*\dfrac{dx}{dt_2}=-1$

Please clarify. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I you can do that, since

$$f(x(t_2))=\frac{d c(x(t_2))}{d x}=c'(x(t_2))$$
$$\frac{d}{dt_2}\left\{\frac{dc(x(t_2))}{d x}\right\}=
\frac{df(x(t_2))}{dt_2}=f'(x(t_2))\cdot x'(t_2)=\\c''(x(t_2))\cdot x'(t_2)
=\frac{d^2 c(x(t_2))}{d x^2}\dfrac{dx(t_2)}{dt_2}=
\frac{d^2 c}{d x^2}\dfrac{dx}{dt_2}
$$